# Getting JSON names from String

Tags: java, json, android-studio

I have a JSON String:

```
{
  06-2020={
    ma01={
      0={duur=Dag, aantalVoertuigen=2, tijd=14: 06, naamHuurder=K, prijs=70 },
      1={duur=Dag, aantalVoertuigen=2, tijd=14: 08, naamHuurder=H, prijs=70 },
      2={duur=Dag, aantalVoertuigen=2, tijd=14: 08, naamHuurder=H, prijs=70 },
      3={duur=Dag, aantalVoertuigen=2, tijd=14: 08, naamHuurder=H, prijs=70 },
      Aantal=4
    }
  },
  05-2020={
    hallo={auto=ja, naam=ja },
    za30={hallo=ja, naam=ja }
  }
}
```

I need to get the 06-2020 and the 05-2020 out of it.

I tried using JSONobject. But that only works with one layer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you paste the code you tried out, we can improve on that.

Comment: Something seriously bad with your JSON. please update if you can or simplify its pattern

Comment: please share your code you tried so far

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Currently the JSON snippet has errors.

Comment: The input string is definitely not a JSON, please revise your question.